# How to clear a file before writing into it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using this code to write into my file:

```
    private async void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String MyScore;

        Double previousScore = 0;

        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var dataFolder1 = await local.CreateFolderAsync("MyFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var file1 = await dataFolder1.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var file = await dataFolder1.OpenStreamForReadAsync("MyFile.txt");

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {

            MyScore = streamReader.ReadToEnd();



        }

        if (MyScore != null && !MyScore.Equals(""))
        {

            previousScore = Convert.ToDouble(MyScore);
        }


        Double CurerentScore = 0;
        Double Total = 0;

        String scoreText = this.ScoreTB.Text;
        CurerentScore = Convert.ToDouble(scoreText);
        Total = previousScore - CurerentScore;


        using (var s = await file1.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {

          byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(Total));
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        }
    }
```

But before writing into it, I want that my file should get cleared. What should I do?

This is what i have tried so far but the problem is that it writes the file up to the filebytes.length and due to that if the new information to be writed in file is less in terms of length in comparison to the privous length then some garbage value or unnecessay thing comes after the end of the new file

Comment: actually i am using fileBytes.Length because of that my file is writed  upto the length of it(Suppose i have 135 in my file the next time i am subtarcting 40 so the result should be 95 but the answer is 955 one extra 5 is coming from the 135 as the 135 has 3 digits so the fileBytes.length make 95 to three digit and the result comes out to be 955)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this snippet :

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
// You are going to replace the file
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    var content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(Total));
    await stream.WriteAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
}
```

To quote the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx) :

> ReplaceExisting : Create the new file or folder with the desired name,
> and replaces any file or folder that already exists with that name.

Comment: ReplaceExisting will not work in my case as i dont want to replace my existing file i want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

I have clear the file by writing a empty string to it and then i have written what i wanted in my file This solved my issue as nothing was there in the file so whatever i wanted to write to it came up successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Stream.SetLength` like this:

```
using (var s = await file1.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    // Add this line
    s.SetLength(0);

    // Then write new bytes. use 's.SetLength(fileBytes.Length)' if needed.
    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(Total));
    s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```